# Define Policy on Azure KeyVault Key using KeyVaultClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-keyvault

I need help to define policy to Azure KeyVault Key (not secret) similar to code below. Since we already have the keyvault created I cant use below code.

**What we are doing**:
We are creating Key and attaching the URL to SQL PAAS for TDE
[SQL Server TDE with Azure KeyVault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql)

Below is the example of creating vault and setting up policy

```
var vault = azure.Vaults.Define(vaultName)
                    .WithRegion(Region.USSouthCentral)
                    .WithExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
                    .DefineAccessPolicy()
                        .ForObjectId(sqlServer.SystemAssignedManagedServiceIdentityPrincipalId)
                        .AllowKeyPermissions(KeyPermissions.WrapKey, KeyPermissions.UnwrapKey, KeyPermissions.Get, KeyPermissions.List)
                        .Attach()
                    .DefineAccessPolicy()
                        .ForServicePrincipal(Azure_SP_ClientId)
                        .AllowKeyAllPermissions()
                        .Attach()
                    .Create();
```

Comment: What is the question ? If you can't modify your code ? what are you asking for ?

Comment: @Thomas I updated my question, hope it helps to answer

Comment: what about using powershell script ???

Comment: Its part of code development and we are using c#

Comment: @Thomas Can we achieve it using powershell ?

Comment: You mean you want to do an update ?

Comment: Yeah from powerhsell you can do an update. I am guessing you can patch/update existing resource from c# ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to define a new policy for an existing key vault and manage sql key in Key Vault, please refer to the following code

```
 var vault1 = azure.Vaults.GetByResourceGroup();
              var  vault1 = vault1.Update()
                        .DefineAccessPolicy()
                            .ForServicePrincipal("your application id")
                            .AllowKeyAllPermissions()
                            .Attach()
                        .Apply();
           var key = vault1.Keys.Define(keyname)
                  .WithKeyTypeToCreate(JsonWebKeyType.RSA)
                  .WithKeyOperations(JsonWebKeyOperation.ALL_OPERATIONS)
                  .Create();
            var sql =azure.SqlServers.GetByResourceGroup(groupName, name);

            SqlServerKey sqlServerKey= sql.ServerKeys.Define().WithAzureKeyVaultKey(key.JsonWebKey.Kid)
                 .Create();
```